# Why are my 6-months old questions suddenly being getting downvoted?

Tags: discussion

My reputation earlier today was 2007. Suddenly it became 1997. 10 reputation losses within an hour. Why? I checked & found that my old questions that were greatly appreciated are simultaneously being downvoted.  My old questions are suddenly continuously getting downvoted for no reason. No comments & no feedback. This seems to be frustating as they were good questions; it is a slap in my face. What step should I take now? The two of those questions are:
[Is it possible to have a rate of change of acceleration?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136880)

[Why do the storms of Jupiter have long life unlike that of Earth?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146488)

Comment: How should we know?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Really, sir, I don't care. But, suddenly many old quo of mine were downvoted suddenly today. Is this a coincidence?

Comment: You had two downvotes and lost 4 points on questions with 20 and 10 upvotes more than downvotes respectively. What's the big deal!

Comment: @MBN: Nothing at all, sir! I've always reiterated that do downvote generously but kindly leave a comment for the downvote. After getting 11 upvotes, suddenly you are downvoted without any reason! That's what my problem:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How should we know?

Downvotes are known to no one except the people who downvote. If this is a single user voting many of your posts down, the system will reverse the votes on its own. If this are several voters that just decided, for whatever reason, to give you some downvotes, then there's nothing to be done - voting is completely up to the discretion of the users.

Comment: Thanks, sir. But really, the questions that were once praised suddenly start to get downvoted. It is really frustrating. Wouldn't it vex you if one downvote your otherwise correct answer for no reason without writting any cause? Do downvote but please atleast write a comment for doing so. Thanks again.

Comment: You are absolutely right Mr/Ms